# What is M4 composite macros, like foreach?

Tags: m4

I would like to use `m4` for doing some type-saving stuffs, so the loop will be definitely needed. When I read `m4` doc, in chapter 6 there is `6.4` and `6.5` for iteration. But it looks like that `foreach` is not a builtin macro (Composite?), how could I use it? In the example, they invoke `m4` with `-I examples` option, and `include('foreach.m4')`, but this file seems not exist with error as:

```
cannot open `foreach.m4': No such file or directory
```

Any help is appreciated!

Li

Comment: Doesn't `M4` explicitly provide `foreach`, or need users to write their own?

Comment: No, it doesn't: the manual provides a composite (read: example of theoretical behavior and how you would call it) `foreach`, but does not _actually_ provide a `foreach` construct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must use a full path as the argument to `-I` (or a relative path, but you must specify the directory).  Note that the examples directory is not always installed along with `m4` (the m4-1.4.1 rpm distributed with RedHat does not include the examples directory.)  The simplest thing to do would be to unpack an m4 tarball and use it.  (eg, unpack the tarball in `/tmp` and run `m4 -I/tmp/m4-1.4.11/examples`)

Also note that `-I` is a non-standard option for m4, so make sure you are actually using a version of `m4` that supports that argument. (eg, `gnu-m4`)

Comment: Thanks William! I would like to know what is the rationals behind this?

Comment: I'm not really sure why not, but as far as I know, `m4` just doesn't look in any default directories other than `.`  Since `-I` is non-standard, it wouldn't hurt anything to patch submit a patch to gnu-m4 that provides that functionality.